# Phonegap - 2.9.0 - Subdirectory issue

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to phone gap and really struggling to get this done.

Basically, the directory structure is like this:

```
/www
   css/*
   img/*
   js/*
   pages/*
   config.xml
   index.html
```

When I try to include add images from index.html referenced in img directory, the image loads successfully. But when i try to reference an image from a page within the js directory, it does not load the image. I do it from a index.js within the js directory.
I provide the path like this when inside the js directory:

```
<img src="../img/abc.jpg">
```

When i Debug using the "phonegap app" , it does find the image, but after building the apk using "phonegap run android" , and loading the app on my device the image does not load.

Also, any page inside the pages directory cannot find the cordova_plugin.js and thus any plugin .js file does not load.

Basically i do not invoke the cordova_plugin.js file. It is invoked by plugin.js that i include in my html.
So basically when in my www/index.html I include

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

and it implicitly invokes the cordova_plugins.js which loads all the plugins. This works fine.
But When inside www/pages directory i reference it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../phonegap.js"></script>
```

and in this case phonegap.js loads successfully but it fails to load the cordova_plugins.js and thus none of the modules load.
Note: I found that the files do not load by debugging it in chrome.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript files are building html to go into the index.html DOM, so you should include the src as it will be referenced by index.html:

```
<img src="img/abc.jpg" />
```

Not sure what you mean here:

> When i Debug using the "phonegap app" , it does find the image, but after building the apk using "phonegap run android" , and loading the app on my device the image does not load.

So, maybe I'm misunderstanding your problem.

> Also, any page inside the pages directory cannot find the cordova_plugin.js and thus any plugin .js file does not load.

How are you referencing the .js files? For **pages/foo.html** it would be:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cordova_plugin.js"></script>
```

But again, not sure exactly what you are after without some code examples.

Comment: I made the required changes to the question for better understanding

Comment: Try peppering the phonegap.js code with some console.log() or alert() lines to find out where it is failing. There should be a function called something like `findCordovaPath`. I'd start there, see whether that gets called, and what it finds.

Comment: The findCorodovapath i am not able to debug. But the image thing worked. Thanks